# TinyMCE or other WYSIWYG with EPiserver CMS 5

Tags: episerver

Im trying to fix a couple of CMS 5 sites to work with a WYSIWYG HTML editor. Ive used this guid to get TinyMCE to work. 
https://www.coderesort.com/p/epicode/wiki/TinyMceAdapter but i get nothing. The guide is using version 3.2.1 of TinyMCE (which is not available any more) but ive also tried with a newer version. 
Does anyone have any experience of this? I need a en editor that works with todays versions of Chrome and IE so it doesnt have to be TinyMCE but it has to run on CMS 5.

Thanks!

Comment: Replacing the editor, while maintaining EPiServer features such as inserting CMS links and images, is a major task to undertake. :/ In short I would strike the option of running EPiServer 5's edit mode in modern browsers...

Comment: I highly recommend moving from 5 to 6 R2 which is still supported and for example recently got an IE11 support hotfix. It's a also an easy upgrade and makes Edit Mode work for most browsers out of the box.

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking your time guys.